# Renaming multiple keys of an object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to rename keys in an object, based on a hash, i.e.:

```js
interface Foo {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}

const f: Foo = null!;
// Change the Foo.b prop to Foo.d and keep the same type
const g = rename(f, { b: "d" } as const);
g.a = 1;
// @ts-expect-error b went away
g.b = 2;
// This works but only b/c I hard-coded `number` in `TValue`
g.d = 2;
```

I think I'm close-ish:

```js
// TODO Don't hardcode `number` here, instead get the T[K] type for the "right K" for P
type TValue<T, M extends { [P in keyof T]?: string }, P extends M[keyof M]> = number;

type Replace<T, M extends { [P in keyof T]?: string }> = Omit<T, keyof M> &
  {
    // K in keyof M where M[K] == P --> use T[K];
    [P in Exclude<M[keyof M], undefined>]: TValue<T, M, P>;
  };

function rename<T, M extends { [P in keyof T]?: string }>(t: T, mapped: M): Replace<T, M> {
  return t as any;
}
```

But the part of "I've got this value, i.e. value "d" from M, what is the a) what is the T[K] "b" for that "d", and b) what is the T[K] type" is eluding me.

I've found a few other SO questions/answers like [Rename keys of an object/interface typesafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871996/rename-keys-of-an-object-interface-typesafe) but they have hard-coded types like `string` in the mapping instead of using `T[K]`s original type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper type that maps original keys to renamed keys and the new type, then extract the type given the renamed key:

```js
type RenameMap<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>;

type RenamedKeys<T, M extends RenameMap<T>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { name: M[K], t: T[K] }
}[keyof T];

type Replace<T, M extends Partial<Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>> = Omit<T, keyof M> & {
    [K in Exclude<M[keyof M], undefined>]: Extract<RenamedKeys<T, M>, { name: K }>['t']
};

function rename<T, M extends RenameMap<T>>(
    t: T, mapped: M
): Replace<T, M> {
    return t as any;
}
```